# Correlation between specifier and qualifier?

Tags: c++, lvalue

`const` and `volatile` are called `cv-qualifier` by the C spec.

What is exactly defference between `specifier` and `qualifier` (`cv-qualifier`)? Is a qualifier is a specifier as well?

Is it necessarry that `qualifier` is with an lvalue only?

What are qualifiers other than `cv-qualifier`?

Does my above understanding make any sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of it doesn't make sense.

*Specifier* and *qualifier* are defined in the C++ standard. *Qualifier* is just an integral part of a *specifier*. For example, *type specifier* in a declaration can include *cv-qualifiers*. I don't see the reason to quote everything from the standard on this topic.

Cv-qualifiers are not restricted to lvalues. Rvalues of *class* types can also be cv-qualified. It is possible to cv-qualify an rvalue of non-class type, but it will have no effect and will be ignored.

The use of `const` qualifier that you show in your example with `foo` is just a syntactic form, which actually means that the const-qualifier is applied to the implied `this` parameter of the `foo` method: `const A* this`. I.e. in this case it does indeed qualify an lvalue, but it is `*this`, not `foo`.

The term *qualifier* also appears in the context of *qualified names*. Name like `some_class::some_member` (or `some_namespace::some_name`) are called *qualified names* and the `some_class::` part is a *qualifier*.

The idea that if something is an lvalue then you can modify it is totally incorrect. There are *modifiable* lvalues and *non-modifiable* lvalues. An object declared as `const int i = 5` is an lvalue, yet you can't modify it. Ordinary functions are also lvalues in C++, yet you can't modify a function.

Comment: +1 for "I don't see the reason to quote everything from the standard on this topic.". Sometimes I wonder whether people think just including some random Standard quote makes their answer less wrong (I'm not talking about this thread, but there are lots of amusing answer threads on SO where that is the case, sadly).

Comment: Hey, someone proved what I claimed yesterday: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51469/dont-forget-to-mention-sql-injection/51474#51474

Answer (score 6):

A cv-qualifier **is** a specifier, actually a type specifier.

**Quoting C++03 7.1:**

*The specifiers that can be used in a declaration are*

```
decl-specifier:
  storage-class-specifier
  type-specifier
  function-specifier
  friend
  typedef
decl-specifier-seq:
  decl-specifier-seq_opt
  decl-specifier
```

... while type specifiers are defined:

```
type-specifier:
  simple-type-specifier
  class-specifier
  enum-specifier
  elaborated-type-specifier
  cv-qualifier
```

As for the distinction between the word specifier and qualifier:

> Each type which
>   is a cv-unqualified complete or
>   incomplete object type or is void
>   has three corresponding
>   cv-qualified versions of its type: a
>   const-qualified version, a
>   volatile-qualified version, and a
>   const-volatile-qualified version. The
>   term object type includes the
>   cv-qualifiers specified when the
>   object is created. **The presence of a
>   const specifier in a
>   decl-specifier-seq declares an object
>   of const-qualified object type**; such
>   object is called a const object. The
>   presence of a volatile specifier in a
>   decl-specifier-seq declares an object
>   of volatile- qualified object type;
>   such object is called a volatile
>   object. The presence of both
>   cv-qualifiers in a *decl-specifier-seq*
>   declares an object of
>   const-volatile-qualified object type;
>   such object is called a const volatile
>   object. The cv-qualified or
>   cv-unqualified versions of a type are
>   distinct types; however, they shall
>   have the same representation and
>   alignment requirements.

While it isn't stated obviously, the above paragraph shows the difference. I admit that the definitions could be more strict however.

Comment: Thanks for the precise reply. In the paragraph you cite I was confused by mixed use of both words: "...The presence of a const **specifier** in a decl-specifier-seq... ...The presence of a volatile **specifier** in a decl-specifier-seq... ...The presence of both **cv-qualifiers** in a decl-specifier-seq...". And as there is no grammar definitions nearby this paragraph, it is not obvious if "const" and "volatile" are specifiers or qualifiers (or qualifier is specific case of specifier or vice-versa). Thanks again.