# Are literal numbers mutable or not?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, rvalue-reference

Naturally, this won't compile:

```
int &z = 3; // error: invalid initialization of non-const reference ....
```

and this will compile:

```
const int &z = 3; // OK
```

Now, consider:

```
const int y = 3;
int && yrr = y; // const error (as you would expect)
int && yrr = move(y); // const error (as you would expect)
```

**But** these next lines do compile for me. I think it shouldn't.

```
int && w = 3;
int && yrr = move(3);
void bar(int && x) {x = 10;}
bar(3);
```

Wouldn't those last two lines allow the literal 3 to be modified? What is the difference between `3` and a const int? And finally, Is there any danger with 'modifying' literals?

(g++-4.6 (GCC) 4.6.2 with `-std=gnu++0x -Wall -Wextra`)

Comment: To answer my own question: In `move(3)` maybe the 3 is copied first to create a temporary int will be destroyed at the end of the statement. Is this the explanation?

Comment: In your second statement: const &z = 3; you are missing the type specifier. so it doesn't compile.

Comment: Thanks, @CJohnson, I normally copy and paste working code in here. But I was careless with that one liner!

Comment: Note that cv-[qualifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610943/) don't really apply to non-class rvalues. Rather than "const", "mutable" is the more appropriate term to use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rvalue reference to the literal `3`:

```
int && w = 3;
```

is actually bound to a temporary that is the result of evaluating the expression `3`.  It's not bound to some Platonic literal 3.

(all the following standards references are from the March 2011 draft, n3242)

3.10/1 "Lvalues and rvalues"

> The value of a literal such as 12, 7.3e5, or true is also a prvalue

Then 8.5.3 "References" gives the rules for how a reference is bound falls through to the last case, which says:

> Otherwise, a temporary of type “cv1 T1” is created and initialized from the initializer expression using the rules for a non-reference copy-initialization (8.5). The reference is then bound to the temporary.

and gives as one example something very close to what's in your question:

```
double&& rrd = 2; // rrd refers to temporary with value 2.0
```

Comment: Thanks, but if that was true, then shouldn't this work? `move(3) = 6;`  Instead I get an error "*error: using xvalue (rvalue reference) as lvalue*". It's time for me to read up on xvalues and prvalues and all that again :-)

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I think I can answer my comment of a few seconds ago. I can see that `move(3)` is an rvalue (clearly, it's unnamed). Whereas inside my function `void bar(int && x) {x = 10;}` there is a name for `x`. This seems to be the difference between `x=6` and `move(3)=6`. Both are `&&` but one is an lvalue and the other is not. And this distinction is what leads to the error message for `move(3)=6`.

Comment: @Aaron: (A late) addition to your comment: Somewhere, the standard specifies that a named rvalue is an lvalue, so yes, that's exactly how it works. :)