# C++ unable to remove constant of an object iin recursive

Tags: c++, constants, const-cast

I have the below function

```
class p{
public :
string const& PrintData() const
{
    cout << "const" << str;
    const_cast<ConstFunctions *>(this);
    PrintData();
    return str;
}
string const& PrintData()
{
    cout << "non-const" << endl;
    return str;
}
private :
string str="Hello";
}

int main()
{
const p p1;
p1.PrintData();
}
```

I am expecting the below ::

constHello
non-constHello

Because i have removed the constantness of the object

But i am getting in to infinite recursive loop

Answer (score 4):

The statement `const_cast<ConstFunctions *>(this);` doesn't do anything useful. It does a `const_cast` and simply throws away the result. The compiler will most likely optimize it away.

Then you do the recursive call, which will just call itself, not the non-const function.

You probably meant to do

```
const_cast<p*>(this)->PrintData();
```

Comment: _"The compiler will most likely optimize it away."_ The compiler will absolutely definitely "optimize it away", in that there is actually no meaningful code that it can create for that statement. It has no analogue in the translated/"compiled" program.

Comment: Or `const_cast<p*>(this)->PrintData()` in fact (no idea what `ConstFunctions` is)

Comment: What if i want to remove the constantness of the object permanently? Is it possible at all?

Comment: @raghureddy That's not possible.

Comment: Thanks, for the quick response. i will do some more research on this

Answer (score 3):

This line...

```
string const& PrintData() const
{
    cout << "const" << str;
    const_cast<ConstFunctions *>(this);   //It doesn't work this way, you didn't use the result
    PrintData();     //THis causes a recursive loop
    return str;
}
```

You have a recursive problem there, You didn't catch the return value of the `const_cast` hence the result was discarded, and the compiler will optimize that line away.

See, whenever you call a member function like `PrintData()` in your code, its called like this

```
this->PrintData();
//actually, like 
p::PrintData( /*cv*/ this); //The cv qualification of 'this' depends on the cv of the object, in your case, const
```

The `this` pointer always carries the `cv` qualification of the calling object. See [What does "cv-unqualified" mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413037/what-does-cv-unqualified-mean-in-c)

What you want to do is to cast away the `cv` qualifications of `this` and use the resulting `this` to call the non-const version

```
string const& PrintData() const
{
    cout << "const" << str;
    return const_cast<p*>(this)->PrintData();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`p1` is `const`, so it calls:

```
string const& PrintData() const
```

In this function you call `PrintData`, but because you are in a `const` function the compiler will look to call your `const` version, which will cause the recursive loop.

The line:

```
const_cast<ConstFunctions *>(this);
```

Doesn't actually do anything since your class doesn't have this type in its type hierarchy and you're also not doing anything with in.

If you really want to call the non-const version then do:

```
const_cast<p*>(this)->PrintData();
```

But you should really ask yourself why you are trying to do this...

Comment: Thank you, it is very helpful.