# Is there a difference between universal references and forwarding references?

Tags: c++, templates, perfect-forwarding, universal-reference, forwarding-reference

An argument to this function will bind to an rvalue reference:

```
void f(int && i);
```

However, an argument to this function will bind to either an rvalue or an lvalue reference:

```
template <typename T>  
void f(T && t);
```

I've often heard this referred to as a universal reference.
I've also heard it been called a forwarding reference.
Do they mean the same thing?
Is it only a forwarding reference if the function body calls `std::forward`?

Comment: See https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers for some background material.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Did you actually read either the question or that blog?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

> Do they mean the same thing?

[Universal reference](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) was a term Scott Meyers coined to describe the concept of taking an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter, which can then be deduced as either a value or an lvalue reference.

At the time the C++ standard didn't have a special term for this, which was an oversight in C++11 and makes it hard to teach. This oversight was remedied by  [N4164](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4164.pdf), which added the following definition to [[temp.deduct]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#call-3):

> A *forwarding reference* is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter. If `P` is a forwarding reference and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction.

Hence, the two mean the same thing, and the current C++ standard term is forwarding reference. The paper itself articulates why "forwarding reference" is a better term than "universal reference."

> Is it only a forwarding reference if the function body calls `std::forward`?

Nope, what you do with a forwarding reference is irrelevant to the name. The concept forwarding reference simply refers to how the type `T` is deduced in:

```
template <class T> void foo(T&& ); // <==
```

It does not need to be subsequently forwarded .

Comment: Nice answer! Do you have any (non-trivial) example where you won't invoke a `std::forward` on a forwarding reference? You can also mention the `auto&&` case for local variables.

Comment: @vsoftco `template <class F> void foo(F&& arg) { use(arg); use_again(arg); consume(std::forward<F>(arg)); }`

Comment: Self-explanatory, thanks, although you still end up with a forward :)

Comment: @vsoftco `std::shuffle`, for instance.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks! Can you explain why it's not forwarded? So you don't "accidentally" end up moving the RNG? But then why passing by forwarding ref? Perhaps I should ask this as a new question...

Comment: @vsoftco Basically, because it's used truly as a "universal reference" (to accept both lvalue and rvalue URNGs) and not for forwarding. See [LWG1432](http://wg21.link/LWG1432).

Comment: Reminder: a type is "cv-unqualified" if it is neither const nor volatile. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413037/what-does-cv-unqualified-mean-in-c

Comment: @vsoftco Yes, a simple range-based for loop for example. I'm not really sure why they felt compelled to use the term *forwarding reference* instead of the well-established term *universal reference* that everyone was using anyway.

Comment: @303 My answer links to the paper which introduced forwarding reference, which provides an answer for "why they felt compelled to" introduce it. You can agree or disagree with the argument put forward there, but you don't have to be unsure of why.

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately, it's confusing, but they are nothing more than two names for the same thing.
Universal reference was proposed (I guess) by Meyers far ago (see [here](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) as an example).
Forwarding reference is picked up directly from the *standardese*. That's all.