# Which constructor is invoked by std::pair when given these value categories?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am looking over the [`std::pair` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) and noticed that when I pass in the following example, the move on the `std::unique_ptr` works but the `std::string` does not get moved.

```
std::string my_str = std::string("Hello World!");
auto my_smartp = std::make_unique<const std::string>();

const std::string &my_str_ref = my_str;

// my_str_ref is fine, no move
// my_smartp is fine, no move

auto pair = std::pair<std::string, std::unique_ptr<const std::string>>(my_str_ref, std::move(my_smartp));

// my_str_ref is fine and was not moved
// my_smartp is has been moved to the std::pair
```

This makes no sense to me as the only constructor I can see valid for this example is `(2)`, passing in two const references which, as far as I know, shouldn't trigger any move. Either they are both passed as temporary `U1&&` and `U2&&` or they are both passed as const references `const T1&` and `const T2&`.

I am using the latest clang if the implementation makes any difference.

Comment: Note that (3) takes more than just temporaries. Those are universal references; they can accept both lvalue and rvalue references (independently of one another)

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552272/is-there-a-difference-between-universal-references-and-forwarding-references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the 3.th constructor

```
template< class U1, class U2 >
pair( U1&& x, U2&& y );
```

U&& is forwarding reference and can bind to both: lvalues and rvalues.

`my_str_ref` is the lvalue

`std::move(my_smartp)` is the rvalue.

The U1 is deduced to std::string&.
x is a lvalue reference:  std::string& - so here the copy construct get's called.

The U2 is deduced to `std::unique_ptr<const std::string>.` y is a rvalue ref: `std::unqiue_ptr<const std::string>&&`.

So pair.first gets copy-constructed from my_str_ref, pair.second gets move constrycted from my_smarp