# How to pass lvalue to function taking rvalue only without templates

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue, lvalue

My question is simple

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void f(T&& i) {
        cout << i << endl;
}

void g(int&& i) {
        cout << i << endl;
}

int main() {
        int i = 0;
        f(i); // works fine
        g(i); // candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'int &&'
              // for 1st argument void g(int&& i)

}
```

Why can I pass an lvalue to templated function `f()` but not non templated function `g()`

Comment: You'd need to move it, the template works because you get typededuction to `void f(int& i)`. The term for the first parameter is universal reference, where as the second is exclusively an r value reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `f()` function does not expect a **rvalue** but a **forwarding** reference.
Despite the fact that `f()` and `g()` look very similar (due to the `&&` symbol), they are very different.
(see for example [Is there a difference between universal references and forwarding references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39552272/11527076))

If you really want to pass `i` to `g()`, you have two options:

- provide a temporary object which is a *copy* of `i` (then considered as a *rvalue*)
  `g(int{i})`
- *force* the conversion to *rvalue* reference with `std::move()`; then the original `i` must not be used afterwards.
  `g(std::move(i))`
  (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer. This is the best written answer I have ever seen in SO. I wish everyone on SO would write well written answers like this.

Answer (score 1):

R-value references is defined since `c++ 11`, You should change your compiler version to c++ 11.

Please check out [this link](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/15-2-rvalue-references/)

Comment: Pre-C++11 compiler would fail on `operator&&` in unexpected place.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I did cast it and does worked in pre-c++11

Comment: Move semantics don't exist before C++11 and `&&` only had one meaning then - logical AND operator. You cannot place logical AND in function argument list nor next to a type. [Online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fOw8VV5wiWWwAA59)

Comment: I gave --std=c++17 flag, its not the version issue, I think George has answered the question correctly