# Constant forwarding reference vs constant reference for forwarding references

Tags: c++, c++17

What is the difference between `const auto&&` and `const auto&` in regard to forwarding references? How do they differ in binding?

Comment: The technically correct terminology for "*universal reference*" is "*forwarding reference*", see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552272/is-there-a-difference-between-universal-references-and-forwarding-references).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the difference between const auto&& and const auto& in regard to universal references?

Their difference is that `const auto&&` is an rvalue reference to const and `const auto&` is an lvalue reference to const. What they have in common is that neither is a forwarding reference. Only `auto&&` is a forwarding reference (or `T&&` where `T` is deduced).

`const auto&&` does not bind to lvalues, unlike `const auto&` and `T&&`.

Comment: Is there any advantage to `const auto &` to `auto &&`?

Comment: @nowi Essentially, the fact that it is not a forwarding reference is an advantage when you don't want to have a forwarding reference. Check [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/bk8j8v/uses_of_const_t/emeu810?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) for a list of cases where the standard uses `const &&`. It's quite obscure.

Comment: Interesting note about `const &&`, I didn't know that and it's very useful, I may use that myself. But I believe I asked about `const auto &` in my comment and `auto &&`, not `const auto &&`

Comment: @nowi Oh, I didn't notice :) The advantage of `auto &&` of course is that you can use it for perfect forwarding.

Comment: so there is no advantage to `const auto &` then?

Comment: @nowi Oh, I still misunderstood/misread the original comment  :D `const auto &` is advantageous when you want to be certain that you don't end up modifying the referred object by accident.

Comment: I see. Under the hood, do the function the same?

Comment: @nowi Reference is just indirection. They are all "the same" "under the hood".