# I still can't get my head around why we need the template for perfect fwd

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

I have this code: (live eg: https://godbolt.org/z/js1qK9hd1)

```cpp
struct big_class
{
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
    std::string s3;
    std::string s4;
    std::string s5;
    std::string s6;
    std::string s7;
};

void func(const big_class &bc)
{
    std::cout << bc.s1 << bc.s2 << bc.s3 << bc.s4 << bc.s5 << bc.s6 << bc.s7 << std::endl;
}

void fwd_func(big_class &&bc)
{
    func(std::forward<big_class>(bc));
}

template<typename T>
void prefect_fwd_func(T &&bc)
{
    func(std::forward<T>(bc));
}

int main()
{
    big_class bc{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"};

    std::cout << "func" << std::endl;
    func(bc);
    std::cout << "fwd_func" << std::endl;
    fwd_func(bc);
    std::cout << "perfect_fwd_func" << std::endl;
    prefect_fwd_func(bc);
}
```

So here fwd_func does not work - but in my mind its basically the same as the template perfect_fwd_func - only its not a template.

Why does this *not* work? - it says it can't bind lval to rval. I think its something to do with the template `T &&` decaying into a `T` or something, but still can't quite puzzle it together... What is the difference between the two?

If I wanted to just pass a `big_class` type around - then I assume my best bet is to just pass it by const reference...

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/what-are-the-main-purposes-of-using-stdforward-and-which-problems-it-solves

Comment: @NathanOliver its definitely related - but I don't think its quite a dup (though I will certainly be reading that), I am asking specifically the difference between `T&&` and `type&&`... but I am sure there are dups out there, I just did not find them yet :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `big_class&&`, which is a rvalue reference and can only take in an rvalue reference, the template version `T&&` is a **universal reference / forwarding reference**.

When you pass in something into the template function, `T&&` might be deduced to either an rvalue reference (`big_class&&`), or an lvalue reference (`big_class&`).

So it could generate 2 different functions for a single type `U`:

```cpp
void prefect_fwd_func<U>(U&& bc);
```

and

```cpp
void prefect_fwd_func<U&>(U& bc);
```

- For more detail, consider [Scott Meyer's Universal References in C++11](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).

---

Go back to your code:

```cpp
fwd_func(bc);
```

Here `bc` can not be passed as an rvalue reference, it can only be passed as either a value or an lvalue reference.

To fix it, you can either create a separate function that takes in `big_class&` as a parameter:

```cpp
void fwd_func(big_class& bc){...}
```

Or, you can specifically move `bc` in the function call:

```cpp
fwd_func(std::move(bc));
```

Or, create a temporary copy from `bc`:

```cpp
fwd_func(big_class(bc));
```

Comment: *universal reference* -> *forwarding refernce*

Comment: ah, its the universal reference distinction between `T&&` and `some_type&&` - and its specifically type deduction that makes it a universal reference ... I think I start to get it thanks :)

Comment: [Is there a difference between universal references and forwarding references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552272/)

Comment: @NathanOliver Added *universal reference / forwarding reference*. I'm a Scott Meyers's fan :D

Comment: @RemyLebeau - ah ha, now my question probably *is* a dup of your linked question