# How to std::forward class template parameter

Tags: c++

I'm getting compiler error when using `std::forward` on a class template parameter, but not on a function template parameter. I'd like to know how to `std::forward` a class template parameter. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class Data_List {
    std::vector<T> data_list;
    
public:
    Data_List() = default;
    ~Data_List() = default;
    
    std::size_t get_list_size() {
        return data_list.size();
    }
    
    void add_to_list(T&& data) {
        std::cout << "\nbefore inside add_to_list: " << data.size() << std::endl;
        data_list.push_back(std::forward<T>(data));
        std::cout << "after inside add_to_list: " << data.size() << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void print(T&& t) {
    
}

int main() {
    Data_List<std::vector<int>> list_of_data;

    std::vector<int> data(100, 2);
    std::cout << "\n1. before size: " << data.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1. before Data_List size: " << list_of_data.get_list_size() << std::endl;
    print(data);
    // list_of_data.add_to_list(data); // gives compiler error here
    std::cout << "\n1. after size: " << data.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1. after Data_List size: " << list_of_data.get_list_size() << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n" << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "\n2. before size: " << data.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2. before Data_List size: " << list_of_data.get_list_size() << std::endl;
    print(std::move(data));
    list_of_data.add_to_list(std::move(data));
    std::cout << "\n2. after size: " << data.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2. after Data_List size: " << list_of_data.get_list_size() << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n" << std::endl;
}
```

This is the error I'm getting `cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘std::vector<int>&&’ to lvalue of type ‘std::vector<int>’`

Comment: what error? Please include the error message in the question

Comment: Since you have specified the `T` as `std::vector<int>`, the `T&&` in `add_to_list(T&& data)` will be instantiated as `std::vector<int>&&`, it is an rvalue reference and you cannot bind it to an lvalue.

Comment: @francesco: You have to uncomment the problematic line [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1f7TaG5or).

Comment: @Jarod42 that's just to see whether I'd get same error in case of template function

Comment: @康桓瑋 but how is it different from `print` template function?

Comment: About `print` it's called forwarding reference https://stackoverflow.com/q/39552272/12416453

Comment: You would have same issue with `print<std::vector<int>>`, but `print(std::move(data))` resolve into `print<std::vector<int>&&>`. In the same way `Data_List<std::vector<int>&&>` would allow your call  (except that `std::vector` of reference is wrong).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In here:

```cpp
void add_to_list(T&& data) {
    std::cout << "\nbefore inside add_to_list: " << data.size() << std::endl;
    data_list.push_back(std::forward<T>(data));
    std::cout << "after inside add_to_list: " << data.size() << std::endl;
}
```

`data` isn't a forwarding reference, it's an rvalue reference, so you can't do something like `list_of_data.add_to_list(data);` because `data` is an lvalue.

To create a forwarding reference, the type must exist as a template parameter of the same function template (Give a reading to the [forwarding references part of this cppreference.com page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) and look specifically at the first example):

> 1. function parameter of a function template declared as *rvalue reference* to *cv-unqualified type template parameter of that **same function template***.

Basically, what you want to do is this:

```cpp
// ...
template <typename U>
void add_to_list(U&& data) {
    std::cout << "\nbefore inside add_to_list: " << data.size() << std::endl;
    data_list.push_back(std::forward<U>(data));
    std::cout << "after inside add_to_list: " << data.size() << std::endl;
}
// ...
```

Then `data` becomes a forwarding reference and does what is intended.

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/fWbhW5PxY)

Comment: I agree with that answer. The proposed solution is rather general. The API is now extended by function calls that will compile whenever T is copy/move constructable by U&&.