# Why does a T&& parameter preserves the constness and lvalue/rvalue property of the argument while a T& doesn't

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue, lvalue

I've just read this in C++ Primer :

> A function parameter that is an rvalue reference to a template type
> parameter (i.e., T&&) preserves the constness and lvalue/rvalue
> property of its corresponding argument.

But I don't understand why T&& parameters have this feature while T&'s haven't.

What's the C++ logic behind this ?

Comment: I feel like this sentence is wrong, a `T&&` when `T` is a deduced template argument isn't a rvalue reference, its a universal reference.

Comment: This reads like a misprint that refers to not function parameters but template parameters. That's an entire different ballgame, and `T &&` is "special sauce" as far as template parameters go. Can you clarify and provide more context of this quote from this book.

Comment: @tkausl they are formally known as "forwarding references" in the standard, not "universal references". See [Is there a difference between universal references and forwarding references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552272/)

Answer (score 2):

Because if `T` is a function template argument, then `T&` is a non-constant reference to `T` while `T&&` is called a forwarding reference if used as type for a function argument. Other `T&&`, e.g. in `template<typename T> void foo(std::vector<T&&> x)` is really an r-value reference that cannot deduce const (not that const r-value references are very useful).

Since we want to automatically differentiate between the following cases:

- `const int x = 5; foo(x);`
- `int x = 5; foo(std::move(x));`
- `int x = 5; foo(x);`
- `foo(int{5})`;

while retaining a single `template<typename T> foo(T&& x)` definition, forwarding references were given the ability to deduce `const`.

As to why `T&` cannot deduce `const`, it likely never was the intent of this feature. It really meant to serve as a non-constant reference to a generic type. It would make `x.non_const_member()` fail to compile sometimes.

Yes, that happens for `T&&` too but the intent here is exactly about forwarding the type as it was passed to us to somewhere else, not necessarily modifying the object ourselves.