Function template correct definition for forward reference to an array and type of element
Minimal working example:
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> struct is_array : std::false_type {};
template <typename U, std::size_t N> struct is_array<std::array<U, N>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<is_array<std::decay_t<T>>::value>
do_something_prob(T&& arr, typename T::value_type mul)  // `arr` becomes an rvalue?
{
    for (auto && v : arr)
        std::cout << v * mul << '\n';
}

template <
    typename T, 
    typename ElemT = std::enable_if_t<is_array<std::decay_t<T>>::value, typename T::value_type>
>
void do_something_no_prob(T&& arr, ElemT mul)
{
    for (auto && v : arr)
        std::cout << v * mul << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    auto arr = std::array<int, 3>{1, 2, 3};
    
    do_something_prob(std::array<int, 3>{1, 2, 3}, 2);
    // do_something_prob(arr, 2);  // error message: 'std::array<int, 3>&' is not a class, struct, or union type'

    do_something_no_prob(std::array<int, 3>{1, 2, 3}, 2);
    do_something_no_prob(arr, 2);
}

What am I trying to achieve: implement a function template that accepts two arguments, (1) a forward reference to any array type and (2) a copy of something of the same type as the array's elements.
This is achieved with do_something_no_prob. But what is the problem with do_something_prob? It can't handle lvalues.

you know what the problem is. Please post the code that has the error and include the error message in the question, then we can explain. currently you are (implicitly) asking us to reverse what you modified in the code to reproduce the error message. You already have the code and the error.

I just added one little sentence at the end. There is not much more to say. do_something_prob simply seems to accept arr as a rvalue only and I don't understand what's the reason for the differences between both implementations. The error message is inserted as a comment in the code.

any detail others have to modify on your code to reproduce the issue is an unecessary source of misunderstanding. You can post the code that others do not have to modify to reproduce the error

you use std::decay_t for SFINAE, why not for T::value_type ? This is basically just a typo https://godbolt.org/z/vdjjnP5eT

You'll also notice that the default argument isn't used in do_something_no_prob since it's deduced so the SFINAE doesn't work. do_something_no_prob(std::vector<int>{ ... }, 2) works and do_something_no_prob(arr, { 2 }) doesn't.

I need some time to get this one.

A slightly simpler version could be template <class T, std::size_t N>
void do_something_prob(const std::array<T, N>& arr, T mul) in this case.

That would not accept a universal reference unfortunately.

btw "forwarding reference" is the more common term. "universal reference" is what Meyers first introduced and once he convinced others that it needs a name, they went for a different one. I don't know the rationale, but I see "universal reference" only be used in older material

this answer has a link to the proposal which explains the rational for the name https://stackoverflow.com/a/39552345/4117728

You're right. Got caught up in some "legacy" discussion and picked up the term again.

@deponovo Re: "That would not accept a universal reference" - No, but in this case, there's no need.

References do not have member aliases. It's the same problem as in
#include <array>
int main()
{
    using arr_t = std::array<int,42>&;
    using elem_broken = arr_t::value_type;          // error
    using elem_t = std::decay_t<arr_t>::value_type; // ok
}

You use std::decay_t for SFINAE, but then miss to use it when querying the member alias.
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<is_array<std::decay_t<T>>::value>
do_something_prob(T&& arr, typename std::decay_t<T>::value_type mul); 

Complete Demo

Thank you for the short explanation. Maybe next time I should also try other compilers. This error message is more helpful note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = std::array<int, 3> &]: type 'std::array<int, 3> &' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members. The "cannot be used..." is the nice/missing part.

@deponovo next time you should include the error message you get in the question ;) Others looking at type 'std::array<int, 3> &' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members and you looking at some other error message is an unecessary source of confusion. Explaining the error message should be part of an answer, but thats not possible when I dont know what error you are looking at.
